# Ciclo anidado, 2 consultas a tablas distintas

Tags: php, html, mysql

Necesito hacer dos consultas a la base de datos y dos ciclos anidados, el problema es que no se como hacerlo, he intentado colocar las dos consultas y los dos ciclos pero no lo he logrado, utilice inner join pero no supe como manejarlo, luego el multi_query, tampoco, las consultas normales como las que les mustro a continuacion si me lo hacen pero no logro juntarlas sin error en la pagina. En la primera consulta se encargara de traer las categorias y en la segunda el contenido que pertenezca en dichas categorias al menos 5 de ellas.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "bnucled");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Falló la conexión a MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT idecat07, nomcat07 FROM catcon07 ORDER BY idecat07 ASC");
$resultado2 = $mysqli->QUERY("SELECT idecon04, nomcon04 FROM maecon04 ORDER BY idecon04 ASC");

$resultado->data_seek(0);
$resultado2->data_seek(1);

//$fila2 = $resultado2->fetch_assoc();
while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '
<div class="peliculas-populares">
            
    <div class="contenedor-titulos-controles">
        <h3>'.$fila['nomcat07'].'</h3>
        <div class="indicadores">
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="contenedor-principal">
        <button role="button" id="flecha-izquierda" class="flecha-izquierda"><</button>

        <div class="contenedor-carrousel">
            <div class="carrousel">
                'while ($fila2 = $resultado2->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo '
                    <div class="pelicula">  
                    <h3>'.$fila2['covcon04'].'</h3>
                </div>
                    ';
                }
                   '
            </div>
        </div>

            <button role="button" id="flecha-derecha" class="flecha-derecha">></button>
    </div>
</div>
        ';
}
?>
<?php
```

deberia quedar asi:

```
<!-- Carrousel 2 
        <div class="peliculas-Accion">
            <div class="contenedor-titulos-controles">
                <h3>Acción</h3>
                <div class="indicadores">
                    <button></button>
                    <button></button>
                </div>
              
            </div>
        <div class="contenedor-principal">
            <button role="button" id="flecha-izquierda" class="flecha-izquierda"><</button>

            <div class="contenedor-carrousel">
                <div class="carrousel">
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/01.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/02.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/03.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/04.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/05.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/06.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button role="button" id="flecha-derecha" class="flecha-derecha">></button>
        </div>
<!- Carrousel 3 
<div class="peliculas-Suspenso">
            <div class="contenedor-titulos-controles">
                <h3>Suspenso</h3>
                <div class="indicadores">
                    <button></button>
                    <button></button>
                </div>
            </div>  
        <div class="contenedor-principal">
            <button role="button" id="flecha-izquierda" class="flecha-izquierda"><</button>

            <div class="contenedor-carrousel">
                <div class="carrousel">
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/01.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/02.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/03.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/04.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/05.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/06.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button role="button" id="flecha-derecha" class="flecha-derecha">></button>
        </div>
                            <!- Carrousel 4 
            <div class="peliculas-Terror">
                <div class="contenedor-titulos-controles">
                    <h3>Terror-Horror</h3>
                    <div class="indicadores">
                        <button></button>
                        <button></button>
                    </div>
                </div>    
        <div class="contenedor-principal">
            <button role="button" id="flecha-izquierda" class="flecha-izquierda"><</button>

            <div class="contenedor-carrousel">
                <div class="carrousel">
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/01.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/02.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/03.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/04.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/05.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/06.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button role="button" id="flecha-derecha" class="flecha-derecha">></button>
        </div>
                                 Carrousel 5 
        <div class="peliculas-Familia">
            <div class="contenedor-titulos-controles">
                <h3>Familia</h3>
                <div class="indicadores">
                    <button></button>
                    <button></button>
                </div>
                </div>
        <div class="contenedor-principal">
            <button role="button" id="flecha-izquierda" class="flecha-izquierda"><</button>

            <div class="contenedor-carrousel">
                <div class="carrousel">
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/01.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/02.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/03.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/04.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/05.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/06.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button role="button" id="flecha-derecha" class="flecha-derecha">></button>
        </div>

        <div class="contenedor-principal">
            <button role="button" id="flecha-izquierda" class="flecha-izquierda"><</button>
                         Carrousel 6 
        <div class="Anime-Infantiles">
            <div class="contenedor-titulos-controles">
                <h3>Anime-Infantiles</h3>
                <div class="indicadores">
                    <button></button>
                    <button></button>
                </div>
                </div>
            <div class="contenedor-carrousel">
                <div class="carrousel">
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/01.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/02.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/03.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/04.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/05.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pelicula">
                        <a href="#"><img src="assets/imagen/06.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button role="button" id="flecha-derecha" class="flecha-derecha">></button>
        </div>-->
    </main>
```

Comment: ¿Como se relacionan las tablas? porque lo que puedes hacer es primero realizar la consulta de resultado, lo iteras y depues realizar la consulta del resultado 2 dentro del ciclo buscando las coincidencias con la id de la primera tabla.

Comment: gracias por tu sugerencia

Answer (score 0):

disculpas a la comunidad, tenia par de dias tratando de solucionar mi duda con las sentencias y mi error estaba en la forma, lo solucione asi:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "bnucled");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Falló la conexión a MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT idecat07, nomcat07 FROM catcon07 ORDER BY idecat07 ASC");
$resultado2 = $mysqli->QUERY("SELECT idecon04, nomcon04 FROM maecon04 ORDER BY idecon04 ASC");

$resultado->data_seek(0);
$resultado2->data_seek(1);

//$fila2 = $resultado2->fetch_assoc();
while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '
<div class="peliculas-populares">
            
    <div class="contenedor-titulos-controles">
        <h3>'.$fila['nomcat07'].'</h3>
        <div class="indicadores">
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="contenedor-principal">
        <button role="button" id="flecha-izquierda" class="flecha-izquierda"><</button>

        <div class="contenedor-carrousel">
            <div class="carrousel">'
            ;

    while ($fila2 = $resultado2->fetch_assoc()) {
                  echo '
                    <div class="pelicula">  
                    <h3>'.$fila2['nomcon04'].'</h3>
                </div>
                    ';
                }
    echo '
            </div>
        </div>

            <button role="button" id="flecha-derecha" class="flecha-derecha">></button>
    </div>
</div>
        ';
}
```

Comment: Considera explicar un poco mejor que modificaste en el código, checa [answer]